# How to properly group and sort c# list array

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Following is my Employee class

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

Assume I have following data

```
    var employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "NA", EmployeeName = "John" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "NA", EmployeeName = "Adam" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "Project2", EmployeeName = "Luis" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "Project2", EmployeeName = "Rose" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "Project1", EmployeeName = "Michael" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "Project1", EmployeeName = "Duke" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() { ProjectName = "Project3", EmployeeName = "Jacob" });
```

As seen above, few employees have been assigned to Project and few of them are not assigned ("NA").
My requirement is to order these employees in below manner

1. First Show all employees who are not assigned to any project with employee name in ascending order
2. Then show the employees ordered by each project and for each project show the employees in ascending order of their name

Expected result for above example (printing project name & employee name together).

```
NA -> Adam
NA -> John
Project1 -> Duke
Project1 -> Michael
Project2 -> Luis
Project2 -> Rose
Project3 -> Jacob
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @PeterCsala i tried few things. I will update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. order by *the equality between `ProjectName` and `"NA"`*
2. then, order by *`ProjectName`*
3. then, order by `EmployeeName`

Example implementation:

```csharp
var orderedEmployees = employees
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ProjectName == "NA") // First, show all employees who are not assigned to any project
    .ThenBy(e => e.ProjectName) // Then show the employees ordered by each project
    .ThenBy(e => e.EmployeeName) // ...with employee name in ascending order
    .ToList();
```

That snippet gives the following result:

> NA --> Adam
> NA --> John
> Project1 --> Duke
> Project1 --> Michael
> Project2 --> Luis
> Project2 --> Rose
> Project3 --> Jacob

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Of3vd8).

Comment: thanks. this works. I was almost close. I tried this 

employees.OrderBy(e => e.ProjectName == "NA").ThenBy(e => e.ProjectName).ThenBy(e => e.EmployeeName).ToList(); 
missed OrderByDescending for first line.

Comment: You were indeed very close. It may not be intuitive (it was not for me earlier), but when ordering bools in an ascending manner, the order will be `false`, then `true`. Like [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cfv6LQ) displays.

Comment: oh. yes. Now in understood the issue. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions should be more than enough for this problem

```c
    List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProjectName == "NA").ThenBy(x => x.ProjectName).ToList();
```

Test it by yourself and play with the properties you can access with `x => x.Properties`.

Just one comment: **Be careful for null strings**. You said you will have "NA", but if there is any null, your sorting will fail. You can add a default constructor or a function to replace null for "" if needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderedEmployees = employees
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ProjectName == "NA")
    .ThenBy(e => e.ProjectName)
    .ThenBy(e => e.EmployeeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorted = employees
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ProjectName == "NA")
    .ThenBy(e => e.ProjectName)
    .ThenBy(e => e.EmployeeName);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
employees
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ProjectName == "NA")
    .ThenBy(e => e.ProjectName);
```